# tile disappearing from rubiks cube with rotation

Tags: java, rotation, rubiks-cube

I'm working on a 2x2 rubik cube, and was having trouble getting one side rotate with my program. The cube is a 2d array of squares. I'm just triying to do a 90 degree counter clockwise turn.

This is what happens
https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Xqg.jpg

I changed the colour so I could see the specific squares and how they changed. I tried changing the order, moving specific pieces at a time to see if the problem was just overlapping pieces (no such luck).

```java
//square class

public class square implements Comparable {
    int c;
    private Rectangle r;
    int xpos, ypos, width, height;

    public square(int a, int x, int y) {
        c = a;
        xpos = x;
        ypos = y;

        r = new Rectangle(xpos, ypos, 50, 50);

    }
    //some unused methods
}

//inside the cube class
public class cube{

square[] temp = new square[4]

square[][] sq= new square[6][4]
//two for loops make squares and fills the sq 2d array
//the result is in the imgur link

public void turnVc(){

    temp= sq[2];

    sq[2][0]=temp[1];

    sq[2][1]=temp[3];

    sq[2][2]=temp[2];

    sq[2][3]=temp[0];

}
}
```

I expect the output to be the original image turned counter clockwise.

Comment: what does this line do `square[][] sq= new sq[6][4]` ? does this compile? is `sq` a Java class? is `square` a Java class? It's confusing without seing the code and not using naming Convention if those are really classes. (Java classes: begin with capital letter)

Comment: Hey AKSW, thanks for the reply. sq is the variable, square is the class. It compiles. The screenshots on imgur are some before and after running that part of the rotate method.

Comment: if square is a class, can you show us it's definition; besides, class name must start with a capital character (Java convention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tmp is a pointer that points to the same object that sq[2] pointers. That's why when you change sq[2] content, you change tmp's as well.
i think instead of assign "temp= sq[2];" you should do the following:

```
temp = new square[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    temp[i] = sq[2][i];
}
```

Edit:
i think a little improvement you could do is that you don;t need to save all the sq[2] array, you could only save the fist item. i would do like this (tmp is now a square, not an array):

```
tmp = sq[2][0];
sq[2][0] = sq[2][1];
sq[2][1] = sq[2][3];
sq[2][3] = sq[2][2];
sq[2][2] = tmp;
```

Comment: Thanks I'm new to coding and completely forgot about pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If your square class implements Cloneable, you should use **clone()** method possible, it is also similar to answer of @Nguyen Tan Bao, but shorter
I guess you 're C++ dev, reference in Java is like pointer in C++, you can research more Have fun !